# Flutter too much work may be done on the main thread

Tags: flutter

I just installed Flutter on Android Studio and already received the following message on the first run (default counter app):

> An Observatory debugger and profiler on Samsung Galaxy S10 is
> available at: http://127.0.0.1:64547/2U5aYG1jE4Y=/ I/OpenGLRenderer(
> 2236): Davey! duration=3491ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=944046286472,
> Vsync=944046286472, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807,
> NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=944047041323,
> AnimationStart=944047066238, PerformTraversalsStart=944047071840,
> DrawStart=947282224186, SyncQueued=947284375075,
> SyncStart=947310119148, IssueDrawCommandsStart=947310506077,
> SwapBuffers=947414413641, FrameCompleted=947563787197,
> DequeueBufferDuration=97265000, QueueBufferDuration=227000,
> I/Choreographer( 2236): Skipped 210 frames!  The application may be
> doing too much work on its main thread.

I'm using Genymotion, so not sure if this is something to be worried about?
In any case, what is the cause of this error, and how do I get rid of the message if it isn't?